# Exception give msg as :"IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandle OrgerView" in C#, What should I do?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

*I tried to connect MS Access Db in C# and want to View all.
My Db connection code is show in below*

```
String conStr= @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SMSGateway2\SMS.mdb;Persist Security Info=True; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=testing" ;

        OleDbConnection con;
        con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        string cmdString = "select * from Temp_Order";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "Student Name: " + reader["SenderNo"].ToString() + "\n" +
                   "ID: " + reader["OrgerView"].ToString() + "\n" +
                   "Program: " + reader["OrderTime"].ToString() + "\n" +
                   "Address: " + reader["Flag"].ToString();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception readexcp)
        {
            throw readexcp;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You are dealing with `OleDbDataReader` then why do you need `ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Answer (score 0):

First remove this line  `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` then check SenderNo, OrgerView, OrderTime and Flag are valid column names.